# Flutter - Positioned Widget in Stack causing Exception

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-positioned

I'm getting the below exception when I try to encapsulate the PandemicCard with a Positioned widget. If I render the card lone/no Positioned widget, it works just fine.

```
I/flutter ( 7331): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 7331): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter ( 7331): RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout.
I/flutter ( 7331): This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put
I/flutter ( 7331): inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
I/flutter ( 7331): The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded height constraint is:
I/flutter ( 7331):   RenderFlex#2b18c relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT OVERFLOWING
I/flutter ( 7331):   creator: Column ← Center ← MediaQuery ← LayoutId-[<_ScaffoldSlot.body>] ← CustomMultiChildLayout ←
```

For this code. Anyone able to help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
class PandemicCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 120.0,
      width: 76.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
                blurRadius: 5.0,
                color: Colors.grey)
          ]),
      child: Text('Hi'),
    );
  }
}

class PandemicCardStackState extends State<PandemicCardStack> {
  // final _cards = <PandemicCard>[ PandemicCard(), PandemicCard()];
  final _cards = <PandemicCard>[ PandemicCard()];

  @override
  Widget build( BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      // This Bombs!
      children: <Widget>[ Positioned( left: 0.0, top: 0.0, child: _cards[0])]
      // This works!
      // children: <Widget>[ _cards[0]]
    );
  }
}

class PandemicCardStack extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PandemicCardStackState createState() => PandemicCardStackState();
}
```

Comment: You cannot only have Positioned widgets as your children of stack widget. You have to have at least one none-positioned widgets.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add an empty `Container` as a `child` of the stack :

```
@override
Widget build( BuildContext context) {
return Stack(
  children: <Widget>[ 
    Container(),
    Positioned( left: 0.0, top: 0.0, child: _cards[0]),
   ]
  );
 }
```

Comment: because a `Stack` widget must have at least one item which can have a static size at build time

Comment: I also had to add                 overflow: Overflow.visible to Stack, to make the item visible.

Comment: @MazinIbrahim that is not true. Just read `RenderStack` documentation. I will copy the part that is relevant in relation to your statement: `[...] If there are no non-positioned children, the stack becomes as large as possible [...]`.

Answer (score 5):

Other workarounds:

**(a)** Wrap the Stack on a Container with a known height:

```
Container(
  height: 50,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(top: 10, left: 10, child: Text('My child'))
  ]),
),
```

**(b)** As suggested add empty Container() and Clip.none:

```
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  children: [
    Container(),
    Positioned(top: 10, left: 10, child: Text('My child'))
  ]),
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this is still an issue. I also came across another option.

You can wrap your stack in an IntrinsicHeight widget as well.

```
IntrinsicHeight(
    child: 
        Stack( 
            children: [Positioned(top: 10, left: 10, child:Text('My child')
        )]
    ),
),
```