# Flutter: Wrap container around Stack with Positioned children

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-positioned

**I want to center a Stack widget** that includes `Positioned` children. The size of the Stack is not known before rendering.

Unfortunately, the Stack seems to have **an unlimited size** (as seen, when wrapping a container around it).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StackTest extends StatelessWidget {
  const StackTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  width: 5.0,
                ),
              ),
              child: buildStack()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildStack() {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        Container(),
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 50,
          left: 50,
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**Final Question:** How can I wrap a container around a stack including positioned children and center it?

*Here are some similar questions, that weren't helpful for me:*

[Flutter - Positioned Widget in Stack causing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621743/flutter-positioned-widget-in-stack-causing-exception)

[Stack makes infinite height if only have Positioned children](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28610)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Stack` needs a reference point. So when there are only `Positioned` items in it, it doesn't know where to start and how big it is.

See `RenderStack` documentation: `[...] If there are no non-positioned children, the stack becomes as large as possible [...]`

This problem was also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54624340/11003497).

**Solution:**

1. One way is to place a non-positioned item **in** the stack, which will become the reference point of the stack (incl. the positioned items).
   This could be a container with a known size.
2. Another option is to set the `Positioned` with regard to global values, like the screen size (see *Priyansu Choudhury* answer)

Answer (score 1):

A custom solution:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
      const MaterialApp(debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, home: StackTest()));
}

class StackTest extends StatelessWidget {
  const StackTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: buildStack(context),
    );
  }

  Widget buildStack(BuildContext context) {
    double containerSize = 50;
    double borderSize = 5;
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 -
              (containerSize + borderSize),
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 -
              (containerSize + borderSize),
          child: Container(
            height: 2 * containerSize + 2 * borderSize,
            width: 2 * containerSize + 2 * borderSize,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                width: borderSize,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 - containerSize,
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - containerSize,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: containerSize,
              width: containerSize,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: containerSize,
              width: containerSize,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But are you sure, there is no way to deal with the stack + Positioned just like a normal widget? Like a container or something?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, Stack takes infinite size until we place it inside a Container and give it a height.